# How can I get an asymmetric many-to-many self-relationship to show up for both parties in a Django restful response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I currently have 2 relevant classes in my model: A `UserProfile` class and a `FriendInvite` class in `models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    username = models.TextField()
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self',through='FriendInvite',
     symmetrical=False)

class FriendInvite(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='fi_sender')
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='fi_invitee')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s invites %s' % (self.sender.username,self.invitee.username)
```

In `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapp.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

And in `views.py`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from myapp.models import UserProfile
from myapp.serializers import UserProfileSerializer

class UserProfileList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
```

I generated 5 different users and 3 different friend relationships. However, when I received the JSON response from the server, it only included the users who sent the invites, not the ones who received them:

```
[{"id":1,"username":"U1","user":1,"friends":[5]},
{"id":2,"username":"U2","user":2,"friends":[]},
{"id":3,"username":"U3","user":3,"friends":[4]},
{"id":4,"username":"U4","user":4,"friends":[]},
{"id":5,"username":"U5","user":5,"friends":[2]}]
```

In this case, U1 sent an invite to U5, U3 to U4, and U5 to U2.  How can I get results for both sent and received invites for users?

Comment: why have you set `symmetrical=False` in `friends` M2M Field?

If U1 is friend of U5, then won't U5  be friend of U1?

Comment: Django wouldn't let me define a symmetric relationship with a `through` argument/relationship for the models.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to define a method in the `UserProfile` class and use queries to get the set of objects I want. I still want to know if there are other ways to do this, though.

```
...
from itertools import chain
from django.db.models import Q

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_friends_both(self):
        invitees_list = FriendInvite.objects.filter(Q(sender=self)).values('invitee')

        sender_list = FriendInvite.objects.filter(Q(invitee=self)).values('sender')
        return chain(sender_list,  invitees_list)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    friend_list = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_friends_both')
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('friend_list','username','id')
        depth = 1
```